# How to split branches on a mercurial repository to make other repositories using HG commands?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

For example, I have the following history on my HG repository (i.e. I created a branch on rev. 80), named "Project X":

```
Project X Workbench:
-------------------------------------------------------------
·   85: Project X: version Z stable
·   84: Project X: improvements based on Project Model #3
| ·   83: Project Model: improvements #3
| ·   82: Project Model: improvements #2
| ·   81: Project Model: improvements #1
|_·   80: Project Model: created
·   79: Project X: code improvements
·   78: Project X: version Y stable
|   
[...]
```

Now I want to have two repositories, "Project" and "Model". The "Project" repository must have the main branch of "Project X" and the "Model" repository must have the branch created on rev. 80 (i.e., from rev. 80 to rev. 83):

```
Project Workbench:
-------------------------------------------------------------
·   81: Project X: version Z stable
·   80: Project X: improvements based on Project Model #3
·   79: Project X: code improvements
·   78: Project X: version Y stable
|   
[...]

Model Workbench:
-------------------------------------------------------------
·   3: Project Model: improvements #3
·   2: Project Model: improvements #2
·   1: Project Model: improvements #1
·   0: Project Model: created
```

How can I do that using HG commands? Or I can do that only "the hard way"?

```
Hard way:
---------
1. create another repository named "Model"
2. rev1 = 80, rev2 = 0
3. update "Project X" to (rev1 + rev2)
4. copy "Project X" code to "Model" folder
5. commit "Model" as rev2 using the same comments of "Project X" on (rev1 + rev2)
6. rev2++
7. go back to step 3 while rev2 < 4
8. on "Project X" strip rev1 and all its descendants
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make you "hard way" a lot easier and shorter (in the assumption you don't rename named branch into default `default` in Model repository)

1. Clone "Project X" repository to (new) "Project" repository, *range* 0:80 revisions `hg clone -r 80 ProjectX Project` (use real paths instead of names)
2. Clone *full* "Project X" into "Model" `hg clone -r 80 ProjectX Model`
3. Enable histedit extension (globally or only in Model)
4. Run histedit with hash of changeset 0 as parameter and "drop" all changesets before rev 80

Comment: Interesting. I'll test it. mercurial. http://selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension

Comment: No, histedit didn't work :( - "histedit cannot edit history that would orphan nodes"

Comment: But this is an approach that could work with slight modifications. 1) Create a new repository. Make a commit in it (e.g. create `.hgIgnore` file). 2) Pull from the old repository (`hg pull <URL or directory> --force`). 3) Take the first revision you are interested in and _graft_ it to the initial commit, then use _amend_ to change the branch name as needed. 4) _Rebase_ the following revisions on the branch onto the grafted revision (use the `--keepbranches` parameter). 5) _Strip_ the remaining revisions from the old repository.